# jQuery .eq() only works on first element in table

Tags: jquery

This only works on the 4th element in the first row of a 200 row table.

```
$('.CSSTableGenerator tr td').eq(4)
```

**How do I get it to work for every 4th "td" in a table row?**

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this

```
$('.CSSTableGenerator tr td:nth-child(4n)')
```

jQuery [**:nth-child() selector**](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

If they are all children of the same parent, you can use the `nth-child` selector to filter it http://jsfiddle.net/T36Y8/ This seems to be your case because you do want 4th starting from each TR.

```
$('.CSSTableGenerator tr td').filter(":nth-child(4n)");
```

If they are not all children of the same parent, you can just pass a filter function http://jsfiddle.net/T36Y8/1/

```
$('.CSSTableGenerator tr td').filter(function(index){
    return index % 4 === 0;
})
```

Comment: Yes, definitely use `.filter()` rather than cramming `:nth-child` into the main selector. Out of interest, `.filter(":odd").filter(":odd")` should have the same effect, though I doubt there's any advantage.

Answer (score 0):

$('. CSSTableGenerator tr').each(function(){$(this).find('td').each(function(ind){if(ind==3){ //do your stuff here}})})

Answer (score 0):

On your code, jQuery filters all `td` matching the filter rule and then takes the 4th one.

Try this:

```
$('td:eq(4)', '.CSSTableGenerator tr')
```

Now jQuery aplies the filter to each context, in this case all the `tr` in a `.CSSTableGenerator` table.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context